# import.io - crawl twitter handles and query

Tags: import.io

I wanted to see if anyone can advise as to the below; for some context before the steps:

The website ( seartwi.com/user/talktalkcare) shows the social media publishing platforms used by "TalkTalk" in the UK, it's on the left hand side under frequently used clients you can see Lithium social web. If possible I wanted to see if I could automate some kind of process whereby the twitter handle can be swtiched from a list of different company twitter handles, i.e. the UFC use Sprout Social (seartwi.com/user/ufc) and then pull back and input the platforms into a corresponding cell/field i.e. talktalk = lithium etc... UFC = sprout social...

Ideally, the setup would be as follows

1. List of companies and their homepages uploaded to import.io (which I've done)
2. Crawl URLs pull back their twitter handles
3. Populate twitter handles into same list as above, beside company name
4. Now use twitter handle and switch out (seartwi.com/user/**HERE**)
5. Then check under

   #### Frequently Used Clients

   and pull back every value in the list

Can import.io do this? can anyone suggest how, I'm pulling my hair out trying!

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, import.io cannot deal with the automated part of this setup. You would have to manually complete steps 3 and 4.

If you would like to talk about a specific site in the future, please contact support@import.io

Thanks,
Meg